# Stop motion animation and audio keyframes in AE

Tags: after-effects, audio, animation, keyframes, stop-motion

so I'm completely new to After Effects (normally work with premiere or stop motion animation) so if I've not given enough/or the right information, just let me know what you need to know.

I have a four frame animation, and want to use keyframes generated by audio to choose which frame to show of the animation (it's for a music video and each frame is a different position while playing an instrument). I was hoping to assign a frame to different value ranges generated by the audio, I've managed to animate other things with audio keyframes and linear expressions. The issue I seem to be having is that keyframes seem to only exist for effects, so I can't figure out how to assign each frame of the animation a value that I can then use in relation to the generated keyframes.

I'm sorry if that doesn't make any sense, but any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which frame of footage is shown by enabling **Time Remapping** for the layer. Find it in the layer menu, or by right-clicking a layer in the timeline, or by using <kbd>ctrl / ⌘</kbd><kbd>alt / ⌥</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

[image: layer menu]

Turn it on for a layer and the displayed time is set by the value of the **Time Remap** property, which can be keyframed or controlled with expressions. Once you've applied it hit <kbd>u</kbd> to show it.

[image]

The value of the property is in in seconds, so you'll have to convert it to frames. You'll have to check what fps value the footage is interpreted as having.